# Can I use standard electrical cable from a waterproof junction box when replacing an exterior light

Tags: electrical, lighting, waterproofing, conduit

I am replacing a faulty exterior light with a waterproof (IP66) LED one with a PIR sensor.

There is an existing conduit through the wall, but it is a thick stone wall of an outbuilding and the provided cable coming from the light will not go all the way through to the inside.

I plan to use a sealed junction box (also IP66 rated) on the outside and run another cable through the wall from it.

Can I use a normal 3-core electrical cable for this, or should this cable also have a waterproof rating?

Comment: "Normal" 3-core electrical cable has a name, NM or informally, Romex.  It is not listed for outdoor locations.  For that, you would use its brother, UF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Normal" 3-core electrical cable has a name, NM or informally, Romex.  It is not listed for outdoor locations.  For that, you would use its brother, UF.

However, if it is all-conduit between the two junction boxes, it is not illegal to use cable, just a major pain.   The more practical choice is THWN-2 or XHHW,  which is individual wires and easier to work with.  Most hardware stores sell it by the foot.  With this wire, there is an indoor and outdoor classification, but generally only one kind of wire is sold, and it is dual rated.

Answer (score 1):

We use sjow cord for lighting regularly the cord is wet rated the w identify this.